# How do I get ubuntu for my Android phone?

Tags: android, phone, smart

Can someone please suggest me on how can I replace my android phone os with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll find all your answers and more over at [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com)